# how to convert pdf to text files n vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

please help mi guys,Im tryig to convert the pdf file into text using vb.net desktop application,
I visited to many websites but they provide a trial version software
there is any solution to to toubleshoot this issue?

My page flow is like :
1) user select the .PDF file from filebrowser
2)then simply click on 'convert to text file' button
3)it will open respective .POF file from the path and convert it to the .TXT file and save it to the specific locaton

Comment: I am curious how you will convert PDF which contains some images, or some fancy font ?

Comment: there is no images or some fancy font  in that pdf its just a simple pdf that contains text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by including this reference

```
pdfbox-1.8.9.dll
commons-logging.dll
fontbox-1.8.9.dll
IKVM.OpenJDK.Text.dll
IKVM.OpenJDK.Util.dll
IKVM.Runtime.dll
IKVM.OpenJDK.Core.dll
IKVM.OpenJDK.SwingAWT.dll
```

try this code

```
Dim doc As PDDocument = Nothing
doc = PDDocument.load(input)
Dim stripper As New PDFTextStripper()
Dim textFormPdf =stripper.getText(doc)
doc.close()
```

Comment: it's working but its just copies and pastes the content without any formating

Comment: @vivekpadelkar well yes. If you want nice formatting, use PDF. Btw the current versions are 1.8.12 and 2.0.2.

Comment: You can use anothe library like itextsharp which provide much funcnality like pdf to text ,pdf to image or pdf to html etc.